# Geoserver VM with NAS, Should I store entire VHD on the NAS or just map the data directory? Or just go with internal SSDs w/ weekly backups?

Tags: geoserver, performance, network

Our humble geoserver instance needs to be able to host GEOTIFF image pyramids ranging in size from a few gigs to a few TBs. A NAS appliance with raid 10 seems smart from a maintenance/expandability perspective but wouldn't a few internal SSDs beat the snot out of it performance wise?

related: [Disk access characteristics of accessing vs building an image pyramid.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175306/disk-access-characteristics-of-accessing-vs-building-an-image-pyramid)

host: 12 core xeon, 16GB ram, windows server 2008 running hyper-v and an ftp server. It has two gigabit ethernet ports and a few USB 3.0 ports.  One ethernet port is reserved for the uplink. The other is not being used.

vm: Ubuntu 14.04 running Geoserver 2.7.2 with 8GB ram and 4 dedicated processors.

uplink: 320/320 Mbps or 40/40 MBps

---

edit:

We need a NAS regardless for imagery backups.   I am leaning toward putting a SSD in the host machine for the VM's VHD, Then I will mount the geoserver data directory on the NAS and perform periodic backups of the VHD to the NAS

Comment: How heavy is the load?

Comment: BradHards at the moment it has about a TB spread out among several image pyramids. We are about to add a single mosaic that is about 2TB in size which will need to be turned into a pyramid. As far as user load. it's all just a test instance right now. We would like to be able to support as many simultaneous users as is reasonable on a 4core vm with 8gigs of ram.

Comment: SSD will help, bare metal will help, performance tuning will help. Whether or not any of that is worth the cost / effort depends on what level you need to get to.

Comment: @BradHards thanks again. I'd like to get a native install going but need to stand the NAS and FTP up first.  Is native JAI still something that helps? The geoserver docs mention it but I haven't been able to find it anywhere.