# Disk access characteristics of accessing vs building an image pyramid.

Tags: wms, image-pyramids

Hosting an extremely large (10-100x ram size) image pyramid via WMS has disk access characteristics closer to a random read, but generating the pyramid is a CPU bound sequential operation right?

Comment: It depends on the algorithm used for resampling, the disk access speed, and the CPU; I'd expect it to be I/O bound.